# Docker uses memory without any image

Tags: windows, docker, windows-services, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am trying to create a docker image from `Dockerfile` on **Windows 10**. Being new to it, it crashed multiple times due to one or more syntax errors in the Dockerfile. I tried to clear all the images by using `docker system prune --all`. I got some disk space cleared up (If I am right, the system here means HDD rather than RAM?). Anyway, I see that `Docker.Service` seems to be using `6+ GB` of memory.

[image]

My question is, is there a way to clear the memory in `Docker.Service`? Why is it using so much of memory when no image is being used? I know that it can be cleared by exiting Docker or force closing it.

**Update**

By the way, I am using `Linux container`, there is an option when right click on the docker icon from the tray.

**Update 2**

I tried all the commands from their documentation page - https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/ - No effect.

**Update 3**

Doesn't seem to clear even when the image is created and saved. Looks like a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Docker creates an image for each command in dockerfile, it creates image layers and stores it in the cache, So whenever your dockerfile execution is interrupted the image remains in the cache. Hence you see the memory consumption.

Try the following command which will remove all the images

> docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)

Comment: I am getting - `unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -aq)
See 'docker rmi --help'`. BTW I don't have any images to remove, so and `docker system prune --all` does that automatically

Comment: maybe you can refer commands here https://gist.github.com/bastman/5b57ddb3c11942094f8d0a97d461b430 and remove unused things like volumes etc

Answer (score 0):

Docker runs Linux containers in a VM on Windows. The 6G of ram is likely what you have assigned to that VM. Use `docker stats` to see the resource usage of containers running inside that VM.

Comment: docker stats show nothing, I was able to build the docker file (finally) but I still see 6GB ram being utilised.

Comment: @akshay The 6GB of RAM is assigned to the VM, not your containers. You can configure the VM to have more or less.

Comment: @Akshay you don't "clear the VM", there's a running kernel that expects to have access to all the ram you gave it when you booted it. That would be like pulling the memory out of your laptop while it was running. You can shutdown the VM, or adjust it. See your docker settings depending on your install type.